# Authentication fail issue in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've got this exception when login action has been failed.

```
| Error 2014-04-01 16:33:49,688 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR [/myproject].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/myproject] threw exception
Message: Cannot get property 'clazz' on null object
```

My config for springScurity in config file is:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'xcom.auth.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'xcom.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'xcom.auth.Role'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistentToken.domainClassName = 'xcom.PersistentLogin'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.openid.domainClass = 'xcom.OpenID'
```

Alos, here is my code in URLMApping:

```
"/login"(controller: 'openId', action: 'auth')
"/login/auth"(controller: 'openId', action: 'auth')
"/login/authfail" (controller:'openId', action: 'authfail')
"/logout"(controller: "openId", action: "logout")
"/login/denied"(controller: 'openId', action: 'denied')
```

Also, Im' using ***spring-security-core:1.2.7.3***

I've googled it and tried different ways but I don't know why is not working.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: So what is the offending file and line? The error log doesn't provide much info.

Comment: Can you confirm all the qualified class names used in config are correct with their packages? For example: `xcom.PersistentLogin`

Comment: Sorry everyone. it was my fault. @dmahapatro Thanks, The problem was about 'PersistentLogin'. The package should be 'xcom.auth' not 'xcom'. After that I've fixed it, everything works fine.